# Automorphism group of a cycle graph in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, permutation, group-theory

From [this lecture note](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs6204/files/Lec5-Automorphisms.pdf), it is known that 
the automorphism group of the $n$-cycle $C_n$ is the
dihedral group $D_n$ with $2 n$ elements.

I use the following code to create a cycle graph of $6$ nodes.

```
g = CycleGraph[6]
```

It gives me the following output.

[image]

Now I use the following code to compute its automorphism group.

```
GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]
```

It gives me the following output.

```
PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2, 6}, {3, 5}}], 
  Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}]}]
```

On the other hand if I directly create a dihedral group it looks as follows.

```
In[15]:= DihedralGroup[6] // GroupGenerators

Out[15]= {Cycles[{{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}]}
```

So, why isn't the dihedral group same as the automorphism group of the cycle graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test that the elements are the same:

```
g1 = GraphAutomorphismGroup[g];
g2 = DihedralGroup[6];
SameQ @@ (GroupElements /@ {g1, g2})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`GraphAutomorphismGroup[CycleGraph[6]]` and `DihedralGroup[6]` are automorphisms. We can use `Equal` to check it:

```
GraphAutomorphismGroup[CycleGraph[6]]==DihedralGroup[6]
```

> `True`